When $x=\frac{u(f_i,g_j)}{v(f_i,g_j)}$ implies $x=\frac{u(f_i(x,0),g_j(x,0))}{v(f_i(x,0),g_j(x,0))}$ ($x=\frac{xy}{y}$ does not imply $x=\frac{0}{0}$)
Let $f_i=f_i(x,y), g_j=g_j(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
$1 \leq i \leq n$, $1 \leq j \leq m$, be such that
$f_i(x,0) \neq 0$ and $g_j(x,0)=0$.
Assume that $\mathbb{C}(f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Therefore, $x = \frac{u(f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m)}{v(f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m)}$, for some
$u=u(t_1,\ldots,t_{n+m}),v=v(t_1,\ldots,t_{n+m}) \in \mathbb{C}[t_1,\ldots,t_{n+m}]$,
with $v(f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m) \neq 0$.
Take $y=0$ in both sides and get:
$x=\frac{u(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))}{v(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))}$.
The problem is that the denominator $v(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))$ may equal $0$.
For example: $f_1=x^2$, $g_1=xy$, $g_2=y$. Clearly, $\mathbb{C}(f_1,g_1,g_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$,
hence $x \in \mathbb{C}(f_1,g_1,g_2)$ and one way to write $x$ is $x=\frac{xy}{y}=\frac{g_1}{g_2}=\frac{u(x^2,xy,y)}{v(x^2,xy,y)}$, where $u=u(t_1,t_2,t_3)=t_2$ and $v=v(t_1,t_2,t_3)=t_3$. Here we are not able to say that $x=\frac{u(x^2(x,0),xy(x,0),y(x,0))}{v(x^2(x,0),xy(x,0),y(x,0))}$, since
$\frac{u(x^2(x,0),xy(x,0),y(x,0))}{v(x^2(x,0),xy(x,0),y(x,0))}=\frac{xy(x,0)}{y(x,0)}=\frac{0}{0}$.

Question: When it is possible to conclude that $x=\frac{u(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))}{v(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))}$?
In the above example (and generally), is it possible to find other $u,v$ for which we can say that $x=\frac{u(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))}{v(f_1(x,0),\ldots,f_n(x,0),g_1(x,0),\ldots,g_m(x,0))}$?

Thank you very much!
Edit: Take $f_1=x^2+xy$ and $f_2=x+y$. Clearly, $\mathbb{C}(f_1,f_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. We have, $x=\frac{u(x^2+xy,x+y)}{v(x^2+xy,x+y)}=\frac{x^2+xy}{x+y}$, where $u=u(t_1,t_2)=t_1$ and $v=v(t_1,t_2)=t_2$. We can say that $x=\frac{u((x^2+xy)(x,0),(x+y)(x,0))}{v((x^2+xy)(x,0),(x+y)(x,0))}=\frac{u(x^2,x)}{v(x^2,x)}=\frac{x^2}{x}$.
Edit 2: Actually, I am still interested in the original above question, not in the solution I have suggested in the comments, so any help is welcome!

Perhaps we should do a shift $y \mapsto y-a$, for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$. For example, $x = \frac{x(y-a)}{y-a}$, here we can take $y=0$; indeed, $x = \frac{x(0-a)}{0-a}=\frac{-ax}{-a}$. Actually, we just applied $g: (x,y) \mapsto (x,y-a)$ on both sides.

Or at first place we could have taken $(x,a)$ instead of $(x,0)$.
